# Unable to focus on cell in onOpen trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I've written a function in Spreadsheet's Script Editor that is meant to focus on cell containing current date. Generally it works when function is fired by menu entry, but after loading spreadsheet it won't focus on any cell.

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Go to Today",
    functionName : "goToToday" // goToToday() contains same code as last 3 lines of onOpen()
  }];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Script", entries); // works on manual run and on startup

  var s = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");    
  var r = 25 + s.getRange("I4").getValue();
  s.setActiveSelection(s.getRange("A" + r )); // works on manual run, doesn't work on startup


};
```

Comment: I've discovered there was created an issue connected with my problem some time ago - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3928 and it was due to Google's intentional (yet unjustified) change. Maybe someone came up with a workaround for this?

Comment: it is indeed... no workaround I'm afraid and , as you noticed, it's a won't fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Bryan's answer, I tried another possible code that would close the dialog automatically.

A few minor changes in the way I call the UiApp popup.

```
function onOpen() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");    
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  ui.createMenu('Goto today').addItem('go !','goToToday').addToUi();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(40).setWidth(180).setTitle('Start');
  var btn = app.createButton('Go to Today in cell A'+(25 + (s.getRange("I4").getValue())), app.createServerHandler("goToToday"))
  .setStyleAttributes({'fontFamily':'arial','fontSize':'10pt','fontWeight':'bold','color':'white','background':'#3870ff'}).setPixelSize(175,35);
  app.add(btn);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app);
}


function goToToday() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");    
  var r = 25 + s.getRange("I4").getValue();
  s.setActiveSelection(s.getRange("A" + r ));
  return UiApp.getActiveApplication().close();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A custom dialog can be shown onOpen...

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Go to Today",
    functionName : "goToToday" // goToToday() contains same code as last 3 lines of onOpen()
  }];
  ss.addMenu("Script", entries); // works on manual run and on startup

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var btn = app.createButton("Go to Today", app.createServerHandler("goToToday"))
  app.add(btn);

  ui.showModalDialog(app, "Start");
};


function goToToday() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");    
  var r = 25 + s.getRange("I4").getValue();
  s.setActiveSelection(s.getRange("A" + r ));
}
```

Just have users click a button to set the active cell.